# JQuery Auto Click on the <a> Tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-click-event

I have the anchor in the HTML page and I want to click on the below anchor **only once** when the page is loaded but it's not clicking on the anchor element.

HTML

```
<a aria-label="Options" class="_5vmb button _p" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;p&quot;}" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Options" data-tooltip-position="below" href="#" role="button" id="js_28" aria-controls="js_9y"></a>
```

I had tried the JQuery as below but it not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('._5vmb button _p').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: where is your div you have posted an `'<a>` tag tho

Comment: What's your expected result? Where is the div in your code?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sorry its <a> tag only I will edit my question

Comment: added an answer @Batman

Comment: did you fixed it or not @Batman

Comment: No I tried all Answered mentioned here none of them working not sure :(

Answer (score 4):

The selector is wrong:

```
(document).ready(function() {
  $('._5vmb button _p').trigger('click');
});
```

It should be:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('._5vmb.button._p').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a aria-label="Options" class="_5vmb button _p" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;p&quot;}" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Options" data-tooltip-position="below" href="#" role="button" id="js_28" aria-controls="js_9y">a tag</a>
```

Comment: To test other way I have tried this as well but it is not showing alert pop up 

`$("._5vmb.button._p").on('click',function(){
            alert('Test');
        });`

Comment: I See two possibilities:

1) You are not loading the script correctly
2) you are generating this tag dynamicly so the listener can't grab it, if that's the case you may want to use "$(document).on('click', '._5vmb.button._p', function(){...});

Hope that helped you

Comment: This is now giving me the Alert Pop Up. But How Should I auto click

Comment: Can u please help how to make it auto click instead of manually clicking

Comment: Sorry For the delay, to make the auto click works, you may want to wait the element to appear before triggering the click, so try a setTimeout for something like 500ms and see if it triggers, if that's enough for your use case, that's fine, if you need it instantly (on apparition), you may need to find where and when (in your code) the element is generated and use a callback function on it's generation to be sure that it's already in the DOM when you try to click it.

Comment: I am even to ready to wait for 5 second I have tried this but didn't work either `setTimeout(function(){
            $('._5vmb.button._p').trigger('click');
        },3000);`

Comment: Well, something must be altering the DOM in the time you try to trigger the Click,
Or maybe the click happens but you don't see, also verify that you have a visuel feedback on the click triggering

Answer (score 1):

try the click event function

Here are the docs for the [click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('._5vmb.button._p').on('click', function(){console.log('clicked')});
    $('._5vmb.button._p').click();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a aria-label="Options" class="_5vmb button _p" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;p&quot;}" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Options" data-tooltip-position="below" href="#" role="button" id="js_28" aria-controls="js_9y"></a>
```

Comment: this isnt valid javascript statement

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yep, fixed it

Comment: I have tried this as well before but its not working

Comment: this isn't correct you donot know what you are doing can you tell me which element you are trying to click and the OP requirements

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('._5vmb.button._p').trigger('click');
   });
```

if i read your html correctly

Comment: To test other way I have tried this as well but it is not showing alert pop up 

`$("._5vmb.button._p").on('click',function(){
            alert('Test');
        });`

Comment: have you included jquery ? are there any errors on console when you load the page

Comment: Yeah I have included the Jquery there and I'm not seeing any errors on Console as well

Comment: do you have a live link to the application / page you are facing the issue

Comment: and when you say it is not working, what do you expect to happen when this click is triggered ?

Comment: As suggested by Tisamu I am able to alert when I try `"$(document).on('click', '._5vmb.button._p', function(){...});`

But Can you tell me how to make it auto click

Comment: try adding `.trigger('click')` in the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159809/discussion-between-batman-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).